# How can I fix Vuejs dynamic image src error

Tags: vue.js

```
  <img
      :src="profileImage"
      alt="Profile Image"
    />
computed: {
profileImage() {
  var profilePhoto = this.memberdata.profilephoto
   return require(`../../../../php/laravel/token/storage/app/uploads/profilephotos/${profilePhoto}`);
}
```

},

Hello everyone, I want to show the user's photo dynamically. When I try the codes I get the following error. I couldn't solve the problem in any way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <img
      :src="profileImage.profilephoto"
      alt="Profile Image"
    />

  profileImage() {
       return {
  ...this.memberdata, 
  profilephoto: this.memberdata.profilephoto && require(`../../../../php/laravel/token/storage/app/uploads/profilephotos/${this.memberdata.profilephoto}`)
}
```

i solved the errror with these codes.